# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute method returns "Bad request" 400

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Good day. I faced a problem: I'm trying to send POST request with some attributes, but I get "Bad request" response.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/group")
public class GroupController {

   private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger
     .getLogger(GroupController.class);

   @Autowired
   private GroupService                   groupService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addGroup(@ModelAttribute("group") final Group group) {

      GroupController.logger.info("I'm in POST method");
      this.groupService.addGroup(group);
      return "redirect:/student/add";
   }
}
```

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "university_groups")
public class Group implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
   Set<Student>              students;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @NotNull
   @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
   private Department        department;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "group_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String            group;

   public Group() {

   }

   public Group(final String group, final Department deparment) {

      this.group = group;
      this.department = deparment;
   }

   public Department getDepartment() {

      return this.department;
   }

   public String getGroup() {

      return this.group;
   }

   public Set<Student> getStudents() {

      return this.students;
   }

   public void setDepartment(final Department department) {

      this.department = department;
   }

   public void setGroup(final String group) {

      this.group = group;
   }

   public void setStudents(final Set<Student> students) {

      this.students = students;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {

      return this.group;
   }

}
```

Here is part of JSP page:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="add" commandName="group">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="group">
                    <spring:message code="label.student.group" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="group" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="department">
                    <spring:message code="label.student.department" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:select path="department">
                    <form:options items="${departments}" />
                </form:select></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="/department/add"/>"><spring:message
                        code="label.student.addDepartment" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message code="label.student.addGroup"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Here is Department entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Department implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "department", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String            department;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @NotNull
   @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id")
   private Faculty           faculty;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department")
   private Set<Group>        groups;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "users_departments", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true) })
   private Set<User>         users;

   public Department() {

   }

   public Department(final String department, final Faculty faculty) {

      this.department = department;
      this.faculty = faculty;
   }

   public String getDepartment() {

      return this.department;
   }

   public Faculty getFaculty() {

      return this.faculty;
   }

   public Set<Group> getGroups() {

      return this.groups;
   }

   public Set<User> getUsers() {

      return this.users;
   }

   public void setDepartment(final String department) {

      this.department = department;
   }

   public void setFaculty(final Faculty faculty) {

      this.faculty = faculty;
   }

   public void setGroups(final Set<Group> groups) {

      this.groups = groups;
   }

   public void setUsers(final Set<User> users) {

      this.users = users;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {

      return this.department;
   }

}
```

If I remove @ModelAttribute("group") final Group group from controller method, all is OK.
Please, help me, I can't understand why it doesn't works.

Comment: Your form is submitting to`/add` but it should be `/group/add`, isn't it?

Comment: @FranMontero If that is the case then return code should be 404 not 400. Right?

Comment: @Nikolai Paste the exception that is thrown on the server side. It is difficult to guess without it. Also there is no code for the Department class.

Comment: Did you check the URI where it goes? If you use chrome do F12 and go to network and check the URI it invokes? Did you manage to find one?

Comment: @R4J Right... I think problem with model attribute validating, but why?

Comment: @NikolaiKovalenko Stacktrace please. Not going to guess without it.

Comment: @R4J It is strange but nothing shows in server console

Comment: @R4J I changed log level from INFO to ALL but server console isn't showing something. May be it is client problem?

Comment: If I remove @ModelAttribute("group") final Group group from controller method, all is OK.

Comment: the problem is you have nested object, which spring cannot understand, like `department`, how could convert a string to object `Department`, if you turn of `DEBUG` level log, you will the problem, there is no easy solution for your case, you shouldn't use entity in controller, you have have another object (e.g. DTO) to contain all your data transfered via http, then build the entity in JAVA code, which should solve the problem.

Comment: Your entity does not look so good. Secondly, post the stacktrace as already told to you twice.

Comment: @We are Borg I told console is empty

Comment: @Jaiwo99 department is object, I put to map list of Department objects with overriden toString() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one except Juergen Hoeller understands `@ModelAttribute` fully. It's as though they created it to scare away new guys.

They really need to change the name to `@ReadModelAttribute`.

You don't need `@ModelAttribute` parameter annotation just to use a POJO as a parameter.

You only need it for one of the following reasons:

1. Read a `flashAttribute`
2. Read a `@SessionAttribute`
3. Read a `@ModelAttribute method` (which should be renamed to `@WriteModelAttribute`)

Since you aren't doing any of those, don't use `@ModelAttribute` parameter annotation here.