# Strange behavior in the working of @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC - 400 status error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

A strange behavior is happening in one of my Spring MVC applications. The annotation @ModelAttribute is working for some entity classes but it is throwing 400 error when used for some other classes. See the sample code below.

My controller code which is throwing the error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addCoursePage(WebRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    Course course = new Course();
    model.addAttribute("course", course);
    return "addCourse";
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/courses/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCourse(@Valid @ModelAttribute("course") Course course,  BindingResult result){

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/courses/list";
    }

    this.courseService.addCourse(course);

    return "redirect:/courses/list";        
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String coursesListPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("coursesList", this.courseService.listAllCourses());
    return "courseList";
}
```

In the above code, in the saveCourse method, the model attribute of entity Course throws 400 error. But there are some very strange observations that I have made. I will list my findings below.

1. This similar code is working for some entity classes whereas it throws error for some classes. This is happening throughout the application, regardless of the controller code.
2. If I change the model attribute to say User class object in the above controller, it works without any error and it creates a new instance of User class even though that attribute is not present in the submitted form.
3. In every form submission, the model attributes belonging to the same set of few classes throw error and the other set of classes work fine. This working and error entity classes set is same every time throughout the application.
4. Even strange thing is that the classes which are producing errors will work perfectly without any problem if I remove some of the other classes which were working fine. Also, if I create a new application with only few classes then also the same code works perfectly for the classes which produced errors in my original application.

Based on the above observation, does model attribute throws error if we have more entity classes and that too for the same classes every time?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32446369/180100

Comment: According to the answer, even if I remove the @ModelAttribute annotation and if I simply use Course course, then also it has the same error. This is applicable for all the error throwing classes.