# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute returns "Bad Request" error 400

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

Dear Spring java Profesionals,
My Problem:
I'm trying to send a POST request, but i get a "Bad Request 400" error.
I find a similar Problem here : [Spring MVC @ModelAttribute method returns "Bad request" 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434489/spring-mvc-modelattribute-method-returns-bad-request-400?rq=1) , but the sulution dosn't help me.

Maybe someone of you can help me.

Here is a part of my MainControler.java

```
@Controller
public class OverviewController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(OverviewController.class);

    public OverviewController() {
        System.out.println("ExperimentController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private ExperimentService experimentService;

    @Autowired
    private TestService testservice;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Testbereich/Versuch/Test")
    public ModelAndView newExperimentTest(ModelAndView model, @ModelAttribute("experiment") Experiment experiment) throws IOException{
         Test test = new Test();
         model.addObject("test", test);
         model.addObject("experiment", experiment);
         model.setViewName("TestView");
         return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Testbereich/Versuch/saveTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveTest(@ModelAttribute("test") Test test) {

         testservice.addTest(test);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/Uebersicht/Experiment");
    }
}
```

Also my experiment.java and test.java entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Experiment")
public class Experiment implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3291761748164983832L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int experiment_id;

    @Column
    private String reader_type;

    @Column
    private String antenne_A;

    @Column
    private String antenne_B;

    @Column
    private String antenne_C;

    @Column
    private String antenne_D;

    @Column
    private String antenne_E;

    @Column
    private String antenne_F;

    @Column
    private String antenne_G;

    @Column
    private String antenne_H;

    @Column
    private String antenne_I;


    @Column
    private String fill_hight;

    @Column
    private int angle;

    @Column
    private String additional;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="experiment")
    private Set<Test> tests;

    public int getExperiment_id() {
        return experiment_id;
    }

    public void setExperiment_id(int experiment_id) {
        this.experiment_id = experiment_id;
    }

    public String getReader_type() {
        return reader_type;
    }

    public void setReader_type(String reader_type) {
        this.reader_type = reader_type;
    }

    public String getFill_hight() {
        return fill_hight;
    }

    public void setFill_hight(String fill_hight) {
        this.fill_hight = fill_hight;
    }

    public int getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(int angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public String getAdditional() {
        return additional;
    }

    public void setAdditional(String additional) {
        this.additional = additional;
    }

    public Set<Test> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }

    public void setTests(Set<Test> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }

    public String getAntenne_A() {
        return antenne_A;
    }

    public void setAntenne_A(String antenne_A) {
        this.antenne_A = antenne_A;
    }

    public String getAntenne_B() {
        return antenne_B;
    }

    public void setAntenne_B(String antenne_B) {
        this.antenne_B = antenne_B;
    }

    public String getAntenne_C() {
        return antenne_C;
    }

    public void setAntenne_C(String antenne_C) {
        this.antenne_C = antenne_C;
    }

    public String getAntenne_D() {
        return antenne_D;
    }

    public void setAntenne_D(String antenne_D) {
        this.antenne_D = antenne_D;
    }

    public String getAntenne_E() {
        return antenne_E;
    }

    public void setAntenne_E(String antenne_E) {
        this.antenne_E = antenne_E;
    }

    public String getAntenne_F() {
        return antenne_F;
    }

    public void setAntenne_F(String antenne_F) {
        this.antenne_F = antenne_F;
    }

    public String getAntenne_G() {
        return antenne_G;
    }

    public void setAntenne_G(String antenne_G) {
        this.antenne_G = antenne_G;
    }

    public String getAntenne_H() {
        return antenne_H;
    }

    public void setAntenne_H(String antenne_H) {
        this.antenne_H = antenne_H;
    }

    public String getAntenne_I() {
        return antenne_I;
    }

    public void setAntenne_I(String antenne_I) {
        this.antenne_I = antenne_I;
    }

}
```

Test Entity

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2345940545223928492L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int test_id;

    @Column
    private int uid_count;

    @Column
    private int speed;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date test_stop;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date test_start;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="experiment_id", nullable=false)
    private Experiment experiment;


    public int getTest_id() {
        return test_id;
    }

    public void setTest_id(int test_id) {
        this.test_id = test_id;
    }

    public int getUid_count() {
        return uid_count;
    }

    public void setUid_count(int uid_count) {
        this.uid_count = uid_count;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public Date getTest_stop() {
        return test_stop;
    }

    public void setTest_stop(Date test_stop) {
        this.test_stop = test_stop;
    }

    public Date getTest_start() {
        return test_start;
    }

    public void setTest_start(Date test_start) {
        this.test_start = test_start;
    }

    public Experiment getExperiment() {
        return experiment;
    }

    public void setExperiment(Experiment experiment) {
        this.experiment = experiment;
    }

}
```

And the relevat part of my TestView.jsp

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="saveTest" modelAttribute="test">
    <div class="container">

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Testbereich</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Erstellen sie ein neuen Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">

                <form:hidden path="test_id"/>
                <form:hidden path="experiment" value="${experiment}"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="input-start" value="Test Starten" onclick="clickStartButton()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 offset-1">
                            <form:input class="form-control" path="test_start" id="start_value" value="" disabled="true"></form:input>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="input-stop" value="Test Stoppen" onclick="clickStopButton()"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 offset-1">
                            <form:input class="form-control" path="test_stop" id="stop_value" value="" disabled="true"></form:input>
                        </div>

                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-uidCount">Anzahl der erfassten UIDs</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control" path="uid_count" id="input-uidCount"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-speed">Geschwindigkeit des Testfahrzeugs in km/h</label>
                    <form:input class="form-control" path="speed" id="input-speed"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Test Speichern"/>
                </div>
            </div>         
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1">

        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function clickStartButton() {
        var datetime
        datetime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
        document.getElementById("start_value").value = datetime;
    }

    function clickStopButton() {
        var datetime
        datetime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
        document.getElementById("stop_value").value = datetime;
    }


</script>
```

I hope that I have sufficiently described the problem. If something is missing write me. Have bear with me, it's my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bad request is due to a binding error due to this part

```
<form:hidden path="experiment" value="${experiment}"/>
```

Spring MVC uses PropertyEditor or Converter strategy to convert from the object type i.e Experiment to String for the value to be used in the form.

It also uses another Converter to convert from the String parameter value on the form to the object field on the model attribute. You need to register converters with your web data binder. Otherwise bind to simple prperties like experimentId and lookup the objects in the controller

1) Define ExperimentToStringConverter

```
   public class ExperimentToStringConverter implements  Converter<Experiment,String>{

      public String convert(Experiment experiment){
         return String.valueOf(experiment.getExperimentId());
      }
  }
```

Alternatively override the toString() method in Experiment as

```
 public String toString(){
      return String.valueOf(experimentId);
 }
```

This relies on the default registered ObjectToStringConverter which utilizes toString() method

2) Define StringToExperimentService

```
 public class StringToExperimentService implements Converter<String,Experiment>{
    public Experiment convert(String text){
       //lookup Experiment probably using  repository
    }
}
```

3) Register the converters with Spring MVC infrastructure

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class ConsoleConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
       public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
          super.addFormatters(registry);
          registry.addConverter(new ExperimentToStringConverter());
          registry.addConverter(new StringToExperimentConverter());
       }
    }
```

If you are using xml configuration you can register your converters as follows

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="example.ExperimentToStringConverter"/>
            <bean class="example.StringToExperimentConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also as pointed with the other answer you need to collect all binding and validation errors so that you can report them to the user

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Testbereich/Versuch/saveTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveTest(@ModelAttribute("test") Test test, BindingResult result) {
   if(result.hasErrors()){
      return new ModelAndView("TestView");
   }
   testservice.addTest(test);
   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/Uebersicht/Experiment");
 }
```

And then add form:errors to your form fields

```
 <div class="col-8 offset-1">
    <form:input class="form-control" path="test_start" id="start_value" value="" disabled="true"></form:input>    
    <form:errors path="test_start"/>                          
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ekem chitsiga for the helpful answer. I think that will be the solution.

I have only a few questions, must point 3) be implemented in the spring servlet? I use xml for that, is there any way to write the configuration in xml?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include xml configuration for registering custom converters

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as it should. How do I know if the converters are being used?

Comment: I do not know why, but the ExperimentToStringConverter is not used. The StringToExperimentConverter, however, already. Thus, the string text in this converter does not consist of the experiment id but of the object as a string (like this "com.ibz.model.Experiment@7cab04ff"). What can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

to know the actual Field Error  problem try this

Add **`BindingResult bindingResult`** after **`@ModelAttribute`**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Testbereich/Versuch/saveTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveTest(@ModelAttribute("test") Test test, BindingResult bindingResult) {

for( FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors() )
    System.out.println(fieldError.getField() +" : "+fieldError.getDefaultMessage());

     testservice.addTest(test);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/Uebersicht/Experiment");
}
```